# Как убрать пустое пространство после Items внутри ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Достаточно распространенная проблема. Вот как она выглядит на деле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После всех элементов списка остается пустое пространство. Оно остается из-за того что `ListView.Height = 610` по умолчанию. ListView не будет подстраиваться под высоту всех своих Items, если их общая высота не будет больше 610.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Как сделать так, чтобы этого пространства (лишней высоты) не было?

Пробовал решения [отсюда](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19874/listview-inside-stacklayout-a-height-problem), но они не помогли...

P.S. Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, варианты с установкой жестко-зафиксированной высоты для ListView. Мне такой вариант не подходит.

---

ОБНОВЛЕНО

Разметка страницы:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <custom:CustomFrame CornerRadius="0, 0, 0, 10" BackgroundColor="#f9f9f9" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                <Label Text="{Binding CurrentTicket.Number, StringFormat='Билет {0}'}" />
            </custom:CustomFrame>

            <custom:CustomFrame Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0, 0, 10, 0" WidthRequest="60" BackgroundColor="#f9f9f9" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Label Text="{Binding TimeLeft}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </custom:CustomFrame>
        </Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding CurrentTicket.Question}" FontSize="24" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#0051DE" Margin="15, 20"/>

        <ListView x:Name="List" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTicket.Answers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnswer}" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <custom:CustomViewCell SelectedItemBackgroundColor="White">
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <custom:CustomFrame Padding="15, 10" Margin="10, 5" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="#F8FBFF">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="17" TextColor="#464E56"/>

                                <custom:CustomFrame.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="custom:CustomFrame" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#9DF2FF"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </custom:CustomFrame.Triggers>
                            </custom:CustomFrame>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </custom:CustomViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <custom:CustomFrame BackgroundColor="#f9f9f9" CornerRadius="0, 10, 0, 0">
                <Label>
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="{Binding TestProgress.TotalPassedTickets}" />
                            <Span Text="/" />
                            <Span Text="{Binding TestProgress.TotalTickets}" />
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
            </custom:CustomFrame>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Дальше" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" BorderColor="#f1f1f1" BorderWidth="1" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalOptions="End" Padding="50, 20" Command="{Binding Continue}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Установить `VerticalAlignment="Top"` пробовали? (или что у вас там на xamarin)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, попробовал - не помогает.

Comment: Какая у вас разметка? Покажите ее хоть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, обновил. Не обращайте внимание на фото. Оно было для примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам столкнулся с этой проблемой и решение было найдено такое: отказаться от ListView в пользу BindableLayout. Пример кода:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
                <StackLayout.Resources>
                    <x:Array x:Key="strings"
                             Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>lol</x:String>
                        <x:String>KEK</x:String>
                        <x:String>Chebureck</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </StackLayout.Resources>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Coral"
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{StaticResource strings}">
                </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Подробнее о BindableLayout [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).

Comment: Кажется, в производительности теряем, поэтому данный вариант лучше рассматривать для маленьких списков.

Comment: @zodiak1 Вы правы, однако, можно попробовать сделать DataTemplateSelector, который будет выбирать DataTemplate с ListView, если элементов достаточно много, чтобы пустого места не оставалось. Это скорее мысли в слух, надо попробовать и понять возможно ли так сделать.